# Case Settings are not being applied when Automated Case User changed

Tags: case, email2case

When I change the Automated Case User from Platform Integration User to a custom User. The Case Settings within Email-to-Case (Routing Address) are no longer applied, i.e. Case Origin, Case Priority, and Case Owner

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the user your changing the automated case user to have access to the inclusion record type?

Answer (score 1):

I hadnt given the new Automated Case User access to the Case Record Types. Once I updated the user - it worked.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386341&type=1